# Issue with refreshing values in a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code:

```
import steammarket as sm
import time
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image  

#Search function which gets the request from the market     
name = ('Operation Broken Fang Case')  
item = sm.get_csgo_item(name, currency='GBP')

#GUI
window = Tk()

window.title("OSMA")
window.geometry("300x110")

Lbl = Label(window, text=name, font= ('Helvetica 9 underline'))
Lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

#Image for case
image1 = Image.open("FangCase.png")
case1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
label1 = Label(image=case1)
label1.image = case1
label1.place(x=20, y=20)

Lbl = Label(window, text='Average cost: '+item["median_price"])
Lbl.grid(column=1, row=3)

Lbl = Label(window, text='Lowest cost: '+item["lowest_price"])
Lbl.grid(column=1, row=4)

Lbl = Label(window, text='Listings: '+item["volume"])
Lbl.grid(column=1, row=5)


#Waits 10 mins, searches again and refreshes value
def refresh():
    name = ('Operation Broken Fang Case')  
    item = sm.get_csgo_item(name, currency='GBP')
    print(item)
    window.after(300000, refresh)    
refresh()

window.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to get the last 3 labels to refresh the values and display them. Although the values are refreshed, it doesn't display the new values instead of the old ones.

I've looked at a previous question on how to do refreshing, and used said code from the question as a basis

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: it seems to me that in the `refresh` function You do absolutely nothing except print out the `item`, first of You are not changing the variables because they are not global, second I don't see You doing anything with those labels, You neither use `.config()` nor a `StringVar()`

Comment: So I made `text` global and added within the function `Lbl.config(text=item)` , is this correct? Said code that I looked at didn't quite explain the process.

Comment: Now that I have added the code I mentioned, the last label is a dictionary which is the format that the module displays the values as, rather than displaying it with the string `Listings: `, If I change the `Lbl` part of the `.config` it fixes itself but I doubt it works to update the values. Some guidance would be appreciated

Comment: would be great if You [edit]ed the new code into the post so we can see what You have changed